# Adding break down of grand total in report

Tags: reporting

I'm creating Salesforce.com report, I need a breakdown of the grand total based on different grouping. Is there a supported way to achieve this? 
Below is my situation:

```
                                            Amount
Summarized by field A (Type1)               1000
    Summarized by field B (SubA)             500
    Summarized by field B (SubB)             500

Summarized by field A (Type2)               2000
    Summarized by field B (SubA)            1000
    Summarized by field B (SubC)            1000

Summarized by field A (Type3)               1000
    Summarized by field B (SubB)            1000

Grand Total                                  4000
    Summarized by field B (SubA)            1500
    Summarized by field B (SubB)            1500
    Summarized by field B (SubC)            1000
```